# @Resource using Spring MVC and tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, datasource

I am learning Spring MVC. I am trying to use @Resource to inject DataSource. It is like this:

### web.xml of Tomcat:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

### context.xml:

```
Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="sa" password="" driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
           url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
```

### The controller code (using Spring MVC framework):

```
@Controller
public class SimpleControllerAnnotation {

//@Resource(name="dataSource")
@Resource(name="jdbc/TestDB")
private DataSource dataSource;

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

//@Resource(name="dataSource")
@Resource(name="jdbc/TestDB")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@RequestMapping("/testDataSource")
public ModelAndView testDataSource() {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String name = null;
    String ID = null;

    try {
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ID, name from STUDENT");
        while(rs.next()){
            name = rs.getString("name");
            ID = rs.getString("ID");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
            try {
                if(rs != null) rs.close();
                if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
                if(con != null) con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    ModelAndView mw = new ModelAndView("TestDataSourceForm");
    mw.addObject("DataSourceValue",dataSource);
    mw.addObject("Name",name);
    mw.addObject("ID",ID);

    return mw;
}
```

In this code, I am using @Resource to inject the DataSource, which I intend to "get" from Tomcat, which I set up in Tomcat (the web.xml and context.xml shared above).

## When I run this program, I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name    'simpleControllerAnnotation': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jdbc/TestDB' is defined
```

The jdbc/TestDB is the DataSource which I set up in Tomcat.

I have following queries:

1) Is it possible to have DataSource which we create in Tomcat to be injected this way? Or we have to use JNDI lookup. In one of the posts that I read on internet, it was said that JNDI lookup is sort of outdated and these days Dependency injection is preferred way.

2) In general, is it best practice to set-up the DataSources in App server/Web Container or to manage in the application itself. From what I read over the posts, it is preferred let App server/Container to manage this.

Any help to past this error really appreciated.

Comment: do you really use @Resource on two places or is it typo? Otherwise it looks like http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/

Comment: @sodik: I tried this, I still get the exception.

Comment: Spring MVC would have its own config file in addition to web.xml and context.xml (of tomcat). The example in the link above I believe isn't for Spring MVC framework. I tried however got same exception. Any pointers which would help to get this resolved higlht appreciated.

Comment: This might be one of the ways: http://www.journaldev.com/2597/spring-datasource-jndi-with-tomcat-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apache Tomcat processes @Resource annotations only on classes that it itself loads (such as Filters, Servlets and Listeners).

   In your case your controller class is loaded by Spring Framework and Spring is responsible for processing the @Resource annotation. Read the Spring documentation (Reference guide).
2. According to Spring Reference Guide [1], the value in @Resource annotation is the name of a Spring bean.

   It says that the name can be used for JDNI lookup if you configure a SimpleJndiBeanFactory, but recommends against it and advices to configure referenced beans explicitly. -> [2]

[1] http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation

[2] http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee

Comment: Thanks! However if we have datastore set up by the application server/ servlet container, in that case how can we use? I thought with @Resouce annotation, we can inject the datasource which I set up in Tomcat. I was able to do so, using JNDI. In effect, is there NO way in which we can directly use the datasource which we set up in App server / servlet container?

Comment: It can be injected, but you need somebody to make the injection. For your controller class the container is Spring, not Tomcat. Read the Spring docs carefully - when Spring performs injection, what it injects and how it is configurable.